# F# or C# | How to test that an extension method is called?

Tags: f#, moq

When I have a **type** MyType and this code:

```ml
// models.fs

type internal Ticker(price:decimal, time:System.DateTime) =
    member this.Price = price
    member this.Time = time

// cache.fs

module internal cache

type TickerCache = {date:DateTime; ticker:Ticker}

let cache_duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds 60.0
let cache_tickers = Dictionary<string, TickerCache>()

let isCached currency_pair = 
    cache_tickers.ContainsKey currency_pair && (DateTime.UtcNow - cache_tickers.Item(currency_pair).date) < cache_duration


let getTicker currency_pair = 
    let found, item = cache_tickers.TryGetValue currency_pair        
    if found && (DateTime.UtcNow - item.date) < cache_duration then Some item.ticker
    else None

// Client.fs

namespace main

open Flurl.Http

type MyType =       

    let getTicker main, base_ = 

        let pair = sprintf"%s%s" main base_
        let cached_ticker = cache.getTicker(pair)
        if cached_ticker.IsSome then Task.FromResult(cached_ticker.Value)
        else         
            let url = sprintf"%s/ticker/%s" apiBaseUrl pair
            url.GetJsonAsync<Ticker>()
```

how can I test that **GetJsonAsync** is called (or not, depending on the result of *cache.getTicker*)?
I usually use Moq to check that a particular *Setup* is called but in this case the *Setup* is on an extension method of the String instead of an interface that I can mock.

Suggestions on how to test this?

(an evenctual C# solution is ok, I'll try to convert to F# or write the test in C#)

**[edit]**
*Why MyType is a type?*
This code is meant to generate a Client that will be used by a C# project in this way:
(MyType is **Client**)

```cs
var configuration = new Configuration(tickerCacheTTL, publicKey, secretKey);
IClient client = new Client(configuration);
var ticker = client.getTicker("A", "B");
```

*type* generate a *class* and that is more ".Net friendly".
Besides, I don't want to pass the configuration to the getTicker function every time.
In the real F# code I use: `interface IClient with` to expose the public methods.

**[edit 2]**
I can use *InternalsVisibleToAttribute*  in models.fs (Ticker, TickerCache) and cache.fs:

```
[<assembly:System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("MyProject.UnitTests")>]
do()
```

(and change TickerCache type from private to internal also)
but I'm still not able to mock cache.getTicker without a proper injection in Client (MyType).

Answer (score 3):

You could inject a function into the type, that would allow you to test by closing over a mutable value that you can check. That would require the minimum changes to what you have to make it testable I guess.

I threw together an example in an fsx script file that I hope demonstrates this.

```
#r "packages/System.Net.Http/lib/net46/System.Net.Http.dll"
#r "packages/Flurl/lib/net40/Flurl.dll"
#r "packages/Flurl.Http/lib/net46/Flurl.Http.dll"

open System
open System.Net.Http
open Flurl
open Flurl.Http
open System.Threading.Tasks

type Ticker = {
    At: DateTime
    Value: float
}

module Ticker =

    type Data(f:string->Task<Ticker>) =

        let getTicker (m, b) =
            let url = sprintf "%s/ticker" b
            f(url)

        member this.GetTicker = getTicker


// in test
let mutable isCalled = false
let spy s = 
    isCalled <- true
    Task.FromResult({ At = DateTime.UtcNow; Value = 1.0 })

let t = Ticker.Data(spy)

let testR = t.GetTicker("whatever", "http://localhost:5000/")

// prod code
let fetchTicker (url:string) = url.GetJsonAsync<Ticker>()

let p = Ticker.Data(fetchTicker)

let result = t.GetTicker("whatever", "https://some.url/")
```

There might be other options using type extensions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/type-extensions)

It might be worth taking a step back and considering whether you can approach from a different way. You might be approaching exactly like you would in C#, when F# might provide an easier, more functional approach. Specifically here I couldn't tell exactly why you had chosen to use `myType`.

See here for some ideas: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Caching

Comment: Thanks Devon for the fabulous reply/tips. I'll try to apply your solution as soon I can. About "why I use a type, instead of a pure-function solution" (I guess is that your question). Probably because this make the "class" more .Net friendly, I'll use this library in other C# projects (I'll check if true and add a comment in my question, in case).

Comment: I can't inject any function into my type (it must be exposed "as it is" to be clear when used by third party consumer). So, the pythonic approach ("spy" remember me the tests in Python) does not work. the _cache_ object is a cache (!) that is refreshed every X minutes (configurable). The idea is to run a background process/timer theat populate a list. It is already a sort of "memoization" (I reuse the list, I don't creatie a new one every time). I'll try to check if "overriding" the  String extension I can replace the Flurl extension so I can mock/test it.

Comment: _cache_ (cache.getTicker) is declared as _module internal cache_.  I must not be visible from outside the library. I can't override/mock it.